# Ubuntu Release Cycle

Tags: lsb-release, 22.04

I am sorry if this question has been asked before. If it has then I could not locate it. My question is regarding the Ubuntu release cycle. It is very confusing to me. The official release date for Ubuntu 22.04 is today (April 21st, 2022). However, it seems the Beta version has been available for at least several weeks now. When I go to the Ubuntu page, I do not see Ubuntu 22.04 as an available download:

https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Listed there are 20.04.04 and 21.10. However, via a web search I can find links to both the Beta release and the Daily Build:

https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04/ (Beta Release)

https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/ (Daily Build)

So which one is the official release? Are either? I realize that it has happened before where the official release date gets pushed back, but that doesn't appear to be the case this time. Would either of these suffice and any changes be available via `apt-get upgrade`? Or should I wait until 22.04 is shown on the desktop download page? This all seems confusing to me, especially with articles appearing in the last 8 hours saying that the official release is here. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you should wait.

Comment: 21-April-2022 isn't over yet... (esp. UTC time)...   It'll be out shortly... a estimated time was *hinted at* so if you saw it why are you asking?  If you didn't - be patient...  It's not long to wait.  You can request an email, so you'll get an email when it's out... Why not subscribe to it if you need to know when.  Alternatively you can watch the various teams tick READY on the public ISO.QA site...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The planned release date for Ubuntu 22.04 is April 21, 2022 but there is not an official time announced for when it will be released. You will just have to wait until it gets released.

Once it is officially released, the release info will be updated in all of the official documentation. If you want to follow the live updates, you can use [IRC](https://web.libera.chat/#ubuntu-release-party) or subscribe to the mailing list for [release announcements](https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-announce).

I actually shared the same confusion about the release date and learned this information after posting a similar question on [discourse](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/is-there-a-place-like-live-time-counter-to-track-follow-see-the-new-release-of-ubunut-version).

Comment: Really? The answer was edited to something completely different from what I accepted? How is that legit @Nmath?

Comment: @LeighK My edit addressed content (ex. the date instead of "today" which will be incorrect any day except the day the post is written) and formatting problems along with spelling and grammar corrections, but it is definitely not intentional to change the meaning of the post. What do you think is different? Perhaps you should suggest an edit? Or let me know what is wrong and I can make additional corrections. FYI- Aravinth gets all reputation from this answer -- the edit is only intended to correct problems, not to change the answer

Comment: @Nmath, other than one typo in the original response I don't see why the answer even needed an edit. It just threw me off. If Avarinth is good with it then I suppose it's fine.

Comment: There are at least half a dozen spelling or grammatical errors in the original text. I also felt that there were some areas that could be improved for clarity.   I'm not saying this to put down anyone and I wouldn't even bring it up except to reply to you. Editing is actually encouraged on Ask Ubuntu, but we never want to change the meaning or intent of the original author.  Please let me know if there is anything that you feel conflicts with the original answer. See: https://askubuntu.com/help/editing

Comment: First of all [Nmath](https://askubuntu.com/users/953371/nmath) thank you for the corrections. And [Leigh](https://askubuntu.com/users/797190/leigh-k), I feel the edited version increased clarity in many aspects. Also as per the site design editing any part of any post is encouraged(as long as it doesn't reduce the post quality) in Ask Ubuntu and I am completely fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not been updated yet, it is available on the Download tab on the Ubuntu homepage (that is `ubuntu.com`).

Hopes this helps in any way possible!